# HTML Select. Select2 + ng-click = Not working?

Tags: html, select, angularjs

I am using `AngularJS`, and `Select2` to create a nice dropdown menu.

I've included an `ng-click` in the Option tag (of the Select tag). However, the ng-click does not seem to be working when in a `Select2`.

```
 <select ui-select2 >
    <option ng-repeat="car in myGarage" ng-click="ride(car)">
    {{car.Name}}
    </option>
    </select>
```

It also doesn't seem to work when using a normal Select tag.

How can I get them to work?

[JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/RH4um/7/)

Comment: Can you provide more details what is not working. It seems all bindings are getting resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use ng-change and ng-model instead of ng-click

```
<select ui-select2 ng-change="ride(car)" ng-model="car">
  <option ng-repeat="car in myGarage" value ={{car.Name}}>
    {{car.Name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why does ng-model 'car' bind to 'myCarTodaySelect2'?

Comment: in the function ride we are assigning the value of car to scope variable myCarTodaySelect2

Comment: when you use lazy select, and fill it when you clicking on select, this solution not good.

Comment: It's reverse in chrome browser, means Select2's menu worked and Normal menu not work &  i checked in Mozilla browser, both are work. I have same issue but i can't getting solution by this answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is the incorrect way to use a select.

First off, there is `ng-options` attribute to a `select` that needs to be used instead of `ng-repeat` on the options.

Secondly, instead of using `ng-click`, you can assign a `ng-model` to the select that updates with the selected car as follows:

In your controller, you need only the following model and you can remove other models

```
$scope.myGarage = [
    {
        Name: "Toyota 86"
    },
    {
        Name: "Hyundai Genesis Coupe"
    },
    {
        Name: "Nissan GTR"
    },
    {
        Name: "Veyron"
    }
];
```

In your view, use `ng-options` and `ng-model` as follows:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCarUI" ng-options="car.Name as car.Name 
    for car in myGarage" ui-select2>
</select>

Using UI-Select2 - Car: {{selectedCarUI}}
<select ng-model="selectedCarNormal" ng-options="car.Name as car.Name 
    for car in myGarage">
</select>

Using Normal Select - Car: {{selectedCarNormal}}
```

This should now work. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fy3Wp/) is a fiddle for the same

Comment: Few remarks. ngOptions directive is not preferred to ngRepeat, it's only an alternative. Both are equally valid but serve slightly different purposes. ngModel is not a replacement for ngClick, but  ngModel+$watcher on model that calls the `ride` method with the selected value is (`$scope.$watch('selectedCar', function(car){$scope.ride(car)}`where `selectedCar`is a model for the ngModel directive on select element).

Comment: Agreed. I did not mean to say that they are replacements, they are just not preferred when it comes to `select`

Answer (score 2):

The OP is using angular-ui select2. The following is from the angular-iu/ui-select2 website:

"ui-select2 is incompatible with <select ng-options>. For the best results use <option ng-repeat> instead."

See the "Working with dynamic options" section at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

So ng-change is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is a lit bit late but i just discover how to make it work:

1) I'm using the original Select2

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

2) the html goes as follows:

```
<select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" 
ng-options="item.label for item in yourVector" 
ng-change="yourFunction(item)" ng-model="item">
</select>
```

3) the script at the end of the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
</script>
```

it works for me :)