# Select options through ng-click is not working in chrome browser using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to use ng-click so that I can pass three parameters and set in my local json based on the selection.

```
<select>                                                             
<option id="" value="">--Select--</option> 
<option ng-repeat="comparison in comparisons" ng-click="setSkillComparisonOperator(index,comparison.sid,comparison.name)"
 ng-selected="comparison.sid == data.value.comparisonOperator.sid">{{comparison.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I can use it ng-model and ng-change as follows.

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="o.id as o.id for o in list" ng-change="onFunction(item)">{{item}}</select>
```

In that case , I can't pass three parameters as follows.

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="o.id as o.id for o in list" ng-change="onFunction(o.id,o.name)">{{item}}</select>
```

Comment: You don't use the object `o` in ng-change as it's only valid in the lower scope. The value of item is valid because of ng-model. Henceforth, `ng-change="onFunction(item.id, item.name)"` would be correct. Also, remove `{{item}}` from inside the `<select/>` tag.

Comment: Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337042/html-select-select2-ng-click-not-working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At last , I found solution.

[JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/g2MhM/9/)

HTML page is

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <select ng-model="selectedColor" ng-options="color as color.name for color in colors" ng-init="selectedColor = check(color1,colors)" ng-change="setColor(selectedColor)">
            <option value="">Select A Color</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Color Id:    <span ng-bind="colorId"></span>
        <br/>
        Color name:    <span ng-bind="color"></span>
        <br/>
        Color shade:    <span ng-bind="shade"></span>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript is

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.colorId = 4;
    $scope.shade = null;
    $scope.color = null;
    $scope.color1 = {name:'Red', value: 'red',id:2};
    $scope.colors = [
        {name:'Red', shade: 'white',id:1}, 
            {name:'Orange', shade: 'red',id:2}, 
            {name:'Yellow', shade: 'blue',id:3}, 
            {name:'Green', shade: 'yellow',id:4}, 
            {name:'Blue', shade: 'indigo',id:5}, 
            {name:'Indigo', shade: 'violet',id:6}, 
            {name:'Violet', shade: 'orange',id:7}
     ];
    $scope.check =function(selectedColor,colors){
        var i = null;
        for(i in colors){
            if(colors[i].id == selectedColor.id){
                return colors[i];
            }
        }
    };
    $scope.setColor= function(color){
        $scope.colorId = color.id;
        $scope.shade = color.shade;
        $scope.color = color.name;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular actually takes care of this form you with `ng:model`. You don't need to pass any parameters.

In your callback function you can do this:

```
$scope.onFunction = function() {
  var id = $scope.item.id;
  var name = $scope.item.name;
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solve this as Krish Lakshmanan did. I also added:

```
<option value="">Some text</option>
```

OR (force to select a member from the list)

```
$scope.options = [1,2,3];
$scope.d  = $scope.options[0];
```

I don't know why but using Chrome with AngularJs, this bug of selection happens, I think problem is at Chrome, because Firefox it worked (I thought firefox sets the value on focus out the input).

> I found this thread here:
>   https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4836
>
> The bug: http://jsbin.com/wofejo/1/
>
> The workaround here: http://jsfiddle.net/JqnMr/
>
> The workaround 2 here: http://jsfiddle.net/y61pacre/
>
> And this issue on chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=415505

I hope I helped someone, if you find the solution without using an empty option or forcing the selection of a member, please tell me! :)