# AngularJS bugs?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I am developing web application with AngularJS v1.2.15, Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152, Firefox version 26.0.

Problems that I found:

1.When I choose ng-options in select tags via keyboard, model updates, but to the ng-model writes first value the first two clicks. Using the mouse works fine. This problem found in Google Chrome. In Firefox all works good. Example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CJPi4gyLeTctzn4dkuST?p=preview)

```
<div class="controls">
     <select id="model" ng-model="safe.model.id"
             ng-options="model.id as model.name for model in models" required>
     </select>
</div>
```

2.In Google Chrome styles are not working for input elements (bootstrap input style and angular invalid class style). I took some screenshots.

Google Chrome: [image: googleChromeScreen]

Firefox: [image: firefoxScreen]

Does anyone else have these issues? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Issue 1: When you say `ng-options` is not working, you mean selecting option using keyboard up and down does not update model? Issue 2: What has style issue got to do with AngularJS?

Comment: Issue 1 - I can't understand the issue. Can you create a small plunkr or fiddle for your issue. Issue 2 - Can you paste the code so that we know what is it that is being done wrong - the image only tells that the behaviour in chrome is different from the one in Firefox - to understand why, we need to see the code

Comment: 1 issue:  http://plnkr.co/edit/CJPi4gyLeTctzn4dkuST .

Comment: Bug can see only from Google Chrome. Because, when I test plunker example on Firefox, data writes to ng-model only after press tab buton and all works fine... And in Google Chrome option value writes to ng-model after every change select option and I get bug. I hope someone will be able to see it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For issue #1, I think its a bug. It's been reported here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4836

There seems to be an alternative though - if you specify an option with a null value, then it fixes it.

So, you can just add `<option value="">Select one</option>` and it works.

Here's a modified [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tMlM4NFMlcdNtnMEfwe6?p=preview) that shows it.

Can you post code for second issue so that we can figure out what is wrong with it? Just images are not helping.

Comment: Thanks. This is one of the solutions. As for second issue, the border of required input is red in Firefox, but in Google Chrome style of inputs is simple and without red border. I use Bootstrap 3 for styling. To see the differences between styles you can in screenshots. Code is on Plunker (the link is in my question).

Comment: Can you create a new question for the issue? Also mention the steps to get the red border in Firefox

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'll try to solve second issue by myself :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know - there aren't any (keyboard) issues with ng-options or the `select` element with angular which probably means that it just isn't doing what you expect it to do. I have created a fiddle loosely based on the code you provided. The following is my controller:

```
app.controller('Test', function ($scope) {
  $scope.models = [{id: 0, name: 'abc'}, {id: 1, name: 'def'}, {id: 2, name: 'ghi'}, {id: 3, name: 'jkl'}];

  // safe has to be defined
  $scope.safe = {model: $scope.models[2]};
});
```

For the `select` element, I started with what you had but simplified it a little bit:

```
  <select id="model" ng-model="safe.model"
          ng-options="model.name for model in models"
          required=""></select>
```

If you take a look at plunker, [it is working here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MO56U7QtsZeB0xwizJP0?p=preview). Note that I wrote and tested this in Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m. I added a focus button so you can test keyboard input (it is hard to focus on the select otherwise).

As to the styling - by default the `select` box in chrome does look different but I can't tell from your screen shots what you consider to be the exact issue here. Hopefully this at least helps with part of your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I created videos that show issue №1.

[Google Chrome example](http://youtu.be/O9zBztlXx00), [Firefox example](http://youtu.be/clJvAsjQFGU)

Answer (score 0):

I anwsered this question at other post, but basically as others said, you can:
1) Add a empty option
2) Force to select a member of the list.

Bellow I have the two solutions and the problem at jsfiddle too.
[Select options through ng-click is not working in chrome browser using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051345/select-options-through-ng-click-is-not-working-in-chrome-browser-using-angularjs/29707282#29707282)

For me this error is a bug on Chrome, not angular, because in firefox worked(when it loses the focus updates the model).

:)