# Using ng-click on the same tag as ng-repeat with argument from ng-repeat scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a select list that is populated with an ng-repeat tag from a list of objects. The name property of each of these objects is displayed in the  tag. On click of one of these tags I want to invoke a function with ng-click, passing the url property of these objects as an argument.

The populating part is working fine, but it doesn't seem like the passing of the argument works. Here comes the code:

The html:

```
<div ng-controller="TaskChartCtrl">
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="project in projectList" ng-click="populateGraphs(project.url)">{{ project.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The relevant part from the controller:

```
 myApp.controller("TaskChartCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {    

    $scope.projectList = {};

    $http.get('URL', config).then(function(response) {
        $scope.projectList = response.data.projects;
    }, function(errResponse) {
        console.error("Error fetching projectList");
    });


    $scope.populateGraphs = function(projectUrl) {
      //FUNCTION CODE GOES HERE
    }
}]);
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to where my mistake is?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you getting any errors? can you post a data sample?

Comment: Hi Tarun. No I am not getting any errors. A sample of the data would be `[{'projectName':'projectUrl'},{'projectName2':'projectUrl2'},{'projectName3':'projectUrl3'},...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `<select>`, you need to use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`

Also use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` for `<select>`

Reference : [Select options through ng-click is not working in chrome browser using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051345/select-options-through-ng-click-is-not-working-in-chrome-browser-using-angularjs)

Try this, set selectedProject inside populateGraphs function while changing

```
<select ng-model="selectedProject" ng-options="project as project.name for project in projectList" ng-init="selectedProject = 'someProjectName'" ng-change="populateGraphs(selectedProject.url)">
<option value="">Select A Project</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Gopinath, I just went for your approach and again the populating is working well. However when I console log the project url argument in the function populateGraphs it returns me undefined on every invocation. So it seems like the passing of the project url is still not working.