# Ng-Click event not working on Select dropdown

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

**HTML**

```
<select ng-click="open()" ng-options="data in datas" id="myid"></select>
```

**Angularjs**

```
Controller('Myctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.open = function(){
     Console.log('No coming here')
});
```

I am using select2 option for same select box using Jquery:

```
$("#myid").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a state",
  allowClear: false
});
```

ng-click is not firing & place holder not appearing on it.

Comment: Do you have any plunkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: No @VinayK Will check if i can create one fiddle, but question is should ng-click work or not ?

Comment: I guess, method name ng-click="Open()" should be ng-click="open()"...I mean, the first character should be lower-case :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Select. Select2 + ng-click = Not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337042/html-select-select2-ng-click-not-working)

Comment: You can use `ng-change` and `ng-model`

Comment: Using jQuery and angular together with no adaptation is very likely to cause conflicts - the two don't know about each other. My guess is that jQuery gets the click event and swallows it, so angular never sees it.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe Same here, but is there any way to handle it

Comment: Many! My personal advice is don't use jQuery plugins, but you could also modify the plugin and convert it to a directive that plays nicely with angular, or (easiest) use `ng-change` as a couple of people have already suggested

Comment: @EdHinchliffe I will try not use jquery, ng-change is not working as well :( THank you

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with ng-change in the select. Runs, but not in the first attempt. This happening if the container select ng-show begins with false and then within the execution is changed to true. If the "father" of select, initially displays (ng-show = true), it works well change the select. Any explanation for this?